# How to make miracast adapter?

Tags: image, wifi, mirroring, miracast

I am a fourth year student in electrical and electronics engineering.  As a graduation project, I will transfer wireless images with miracast protocol.miracast adapter) (Google Chromecast, Microsoft Wireless Display etc. ) But I couldn't find any resources on how to do it.  Any suggestions?

Answer (score 1):

I appreciate your intent to do something out of the box , I can suggest couple of adapters which supports miracast, if you go through the architecture of those I think it will help u in some way as you want to make a adapter.

1) Asus AC56

2) Linksys WUSB6300

or

If you want to do a project on miracast then there are some opensource projects which u can refer

1) [https://github.com/intel/wds].

2) [https://github.com/albfan/miraclecast].

I hope this helps you in some way :).